# Create new array sorted by time

Tags: javascript

I have an object with a path and a timestamp that looks like this:

```
{
    events: [
        {
            path: '/src/IMG__0001.jpg',
            time: '2011:03:11 11:29:27'
        },
        {
            path: '/src/IMG__0002.jpg',
            time: '2011:03:11 11:29:32'
        },
        {
            path: '/src/IMG__0003.jpg',
            time: '2011:03:11 11:29:37'
        },
        {
            path: '/src/IMG__0004.jpg',
            time: '2011:03:11 12:49:58'
        },
        {
            path: '/src/IMG__0005.jpg',
            time: '2011:03:11 12:50:14'
        },
        {
            path: '/src/IMG__0334.jpg',
            time: '2011:03:13 22:36:47'
        },
        {
            path: '/src/IMG__0335.jpg',
            time: '2011:03:13 22:38:49'
        }
    ]
}
```

Now, I want to sort it and create a new object with the following structure:

```
{
    events: [ 
        {
            date: '11.03.2011',
            imgs: [
                {
                    path: '/src/IMG__0001.jpg',
                    time: '2011:03:11 11:29:27'
                },
                {
                    path: '/src/IMG__0002.jpg',
                    time: '2011:03:11 11:29:32'
                },
                {
                    path: '/src/IMG__0003.jpg',
                    time: '2011:03:11 11:29:37'
                },
                {
                    path: '/src/IMG__0004.jpg',
                    time: '2011:03:11 12:49:58'
                },
                {
                    path: '/src/IMG__0005.jpg',
                    time: '2011:03:11 12:50:14'
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            date: '13.03.2011',
            imgs: [
                {
                    path: '/src/IMG__0334.jpg',
                    time: '2011:03:13 22:36:47'
                },
                {
                    path: '/src/IMG__0335.jpg',
                    time: '2011:03:13 22:38:49'
                }
            ]
        } 
    ]
}
```

I know that I have to compare the "time"-values and in case of a new day, I have to create a new insert with "date" in my object.

Comment: Unless you're dealing with strings you're reading from somewhere, this has nothing to do with JSON. These are just JavaScript objects. JSON is just a textual data notation, like HTML or XML before you read it into a DOM.

Comment: You example structure for your desired end result is invalid. You'll need to make the values of your `imgs` properties arrays.

Comment: You are right, this are my JS-Objects and I parse them later with a library to Json. Sorry, I explained it bad and edit my question.

Comment: Is the date-time-format fixed and are the entries ordered by date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difficult part is those dates are a pain to parse since the month/year/day parts are separated by `:` and not `-` so we can easily convert to ISODates to make the `new Date` part work correctly.

I'm sorting the `imgs` array on each loop so this isn't performant -- that's an exercise left to the reader.

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7aekr/) for this.

```
var input = {
    events: [
        {
            path: '/src/IMG__0001.jpg',
            time: '2011:03:11 11:29:27'
        },
        {
            path: '/src/IMG__0002.jpg',
            time: '2011:03:11 11:29:32'
        },
        {
            path: '/src/IMG__0003.jpg',
            time: '2011:03:11 11:29:37'
        },
        {
            path: '/src/IMG__0004.jpg',
            time: '2011:03:11 12:49:58'
        },
        {
            path: '/src/IMG__0005.jpg',
            time: '2011:03:11 12:50:14'
        },
        {
            path: '/src/IMG__0334.jpg',
            time: '2011:03:13 22:36:47'
        },
        {
            path: '/src/IMG__0335.jpg',
            time: '2011:03:13 22:38:49'
        }
    ]
};


var output = {
  events: []
};


function makeEventDay(d){
  var day = d.getDate() < 10 ? '0'+d.getDate() : d.getDate();
  var month = (d.getMonth()+1 )< 10 ? '0'+(d.getMonth()+1) : (d.getMonth()+1);
  return [day, month, d.getFullYear()].join('.');
}

function getDate(d){
  var dateString = d.split(' ');
  dateString[0] = dateString[0].replace(/:/g, '-');
  dateString = dateString.join('T');
  return new Date(dateString);
}


input.events.forEach(function(event){
  var eventTime = getDate(event.time);
  var eventDay = makeEventDay(eventTime);
  var eventBlock = output.events.filter(function(e){
    return e.date === eventDay;
  })[0];

  if(!eventBlock){
      eventBlock = {
      date: eventDay,
      imgs: []
    };
    output.events.push(eventBlock);
  }

  eventBlock.imgs.push(event);
  eventBlock.imgs.sort(function(a, b){
    return new Date(a.time) - new Date(b.time);
  });
});

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

This code will group the images by date and sort each set of images in the groups

```
//var array = your images

var output = [],
    seenDates = {}

for (var i = 0, _len = array.length; i < _len; i++) {
    var image = array[i],
        timeSplit = image.time.split(" "),
        date = timeSplit[0].replace(/:/g,".")

    if ( !seenDates[date] ) {
        //create an object
        var obj = {
            date: date,
            imgs: [image]
        }

        //push it into the output, and seenDates object for easy access, changes in seenDates will be reflected in output to prevent nesting loops
        output.push(obj)
        seenDates[date] = {
            "_ref": obj
        }
    } else {
        seenDates[date]["_ref"].imgs.push(image)        
    }
}

//Start Sorting
var formatDate = function(dateString) {
    dateString = dateString.split(" ")
    dateString[0].replace(/:/g,".")
    return dateString.join(" ")
}

output = output.sort(function(a,b){
    return new Date(a.date) > new Date(b.date)
})

for ( var i = 0, _len = output.length; i < _len; i++ ) {
    var images = output[i].imgs

    images = images.sort(function(a,b){            
        return new Date(formatDate(a.time)) > new Date(formatDate(b.time))
    })
}
```

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/879Lr/3/

Comment: Why not sort them? You can pass a comparator function to [`Array.prototype.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)